# Introductory literature on the Voter Model

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling

I am looking for a good introduction to the voter model appropriate for the Bachelor-Maths level (Europe). I need something that introduces the model on a low level, as a Glauber dynamics or similar.

I did find the books by Ligett who introduced the topic, but other than that I can't seem to find anything suitable.

Does anyone know a good book or lecture notes on the topic?

Answer (score 1):

This is a recent review article: [Reality Inspired Voter Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11888) (2019).